# How to convert a string to number in scheme without removing the leading zero?

Tags: string, numbers, scheme, racket

I want to convert a string to a number in Scheme, but when I use the function string->number it removes the leading zero

For example
(string->number "01") gives me 1
Is there a way to convert the string so that it doesnt remove the leading zero and gives me 01 instead?

Comment: As *numbers*, 01 and 1 are the same identical value.

Comment: And I want to write down a play, but wonder how I can retain the voice of the actors on paper.

Answer (score 3):

You can't: leading zeros are just part of the written representation of numbers, not part of the number itself. In particular `01`, `1` and `00000001` are all the same number.

If you want to *print* numbers with leading zeros, for instance to line things up, then there are utilities which do that.  For instance in Racket, while the `format` / `printf` family of procedures cannot do this, the procedures provided by `racket/format` *can*:

```lisp
> (require racket/format)
> (~a 1 #:width 2 #:align 'right #:pad-string "0")
"01"
```

However you will still need to deal with negative numbers yourself, which is rather annoying.